# How do I visualize the histograms of the layers of an RNN in tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have subclassed `RNNCell` as the building block of my RNN. I put an instance of this object into `tf.dynamic_rnn` and then I define a prediction function in my `Agent` class:

```
class Agent():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def predictions(self):
        cell = RNNCell()
        output, last_state = tf.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs = ...)
        return output
```

Everything works fine, but how do I add a histogram for the layers now? I've tried to do it in the `RNNCell` but it doesn't work:

```
class RNNCell(tf.nn.rnn_cell.RNNCell):
    def __init__(self):
        super(RNNCell, self).__init__()
        self._output_size = 15
        self._state_size = 15
        self._histogram1 = None

    def __call__(self, X, state):
        network = tflearn.layers.conv_2d(X, 5, [1, 3], activation='relu', weights_init=tflearn.initializations.variance_scaling(), padding="valid")
        self._histogram1 = tf.summary.histogram("layer1_hist_summary", network)
        ...

    @property
    def histogram1(self):
    return self._histogram1
```

and then

```
class Agent():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def predictions(self):
        cell = RNNCell()
        self.histogram1 = cell.histogram1
        output, last_state = tf.dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs = ...)
        return output
```

Later when I run `sess.run(agent.histogram1, feed_dict=...)` I get the error `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the value of Agent's self.histogram1 never got updated to reflect that summary assigned in RNNCell.

Your code for the Agent predictions() method initializes Agent's histogram1 value to None here:

```
cell = RNNCell()  #invoks __init__() so RNNCELL's histogram1 is now None
self.histogram1 = cell.histogram1
```

When RNNCell's `__call__()` method is invoked, it updates the RNNCell's value of histogram1

```
self._histogram1 = tf.summary.histogram("layer1_hist_summary", network)
```

But the Agent's copy of histogram1 was apparently not updated, so when the call is made:

```
sess.run(agent.histogram1, feed_dict=...)
```

agent.histogram1 is still None.

I don't see in the posted code where the summaries were merged before training, so the missing step is likely in unposted code somewhere.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that `agent.histogram1` is None (it's not necessary to merge the summaries, let's assume this is the only summary that I have). Do I need a way of reaching into `cell` directly?

Comment: I'd have to see the structure of how cell and agent comes into play during training, but I'm not quite  sure why the histogram needs to be shared among the two.

Comment: It probably doesn't, I was only fishing for a solution. During training I initialize an agent object with the desired parameters and then I evaluate things like `sess.run([agent.predictions, agent.loss, agent.optimize], feed_dict=...)` I never touch the cell directly, it gets initialized inside the agent object.